# Given a simple e-mail/password authentication scheme in Firebase, what is the most appropriate method of expedited login?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm writing an android app that requires login for access to our Firebase details. I'm currently using the "e-mail & password" authentication method. What I would like to implement is some fast login procedure once the user has logged into the app at least once. If I didn't care at all about security or best practices, the way to do this would be to squirrel away the user's credentials in some file local to the device. But I do.

Some googling suggests using OAUTH, but if I understand correctly, that would require a user to have an account with a supporting service (Google, Facebook, Twitter, Github). That association doesn't feel appropriate for this app's branding. An independent e-mail password fits better.

So what would you all suggest for an implementation of fast login machinery?

Edit: forgot to mention, if the suggested methods have a specifiable expiration, thats a plus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference.
When user login first time save uId in shared preference and check every time when user come to your app that uId is exist or not if exist no need to do login.
And when user logout from application clear all shared preference.

Comment: This would work... It doesn't address my desire for an expiration date (see my edit), but I suppose I can implement that with a AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication automatically keeps the user signed in across app restarts. If you attach an `onAuthStateChanged` listener when the app restarts, the user can continue working without having to sign in again.

See this example from the documentation for [getting the currently signed-in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> The recommended way to get the current user is by setting a listener on the `FirebaseAuth` object:
>
> ```
> FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
>         FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
>         if (user != null) {
>             // User is signed in
>             Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
>         } else {
>             // User is signed out
>             Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
>         }
>         // ...
>     }
> });
> ```

Comment: oh yeah. I did see this method. I rejected it because at the time I was hoping to find something that had an expiration that I could specify... still, that's the best option I've come across so far.